# How to prompt only users who updated the app (iOS)?

Tags: ios

I have an app update where I'd like to present a notification to users who already had a previous version of the app, no new downloads. Unfortunately I didn't write any guaranteed values to memory in the previous version, so I don't have anything solid to check against. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The app store will prompt the user if the user allows it in the phone settings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no experience with ios, so here's some general steps:

(Note: Added the answer for both the question title, and the question body, because they don't match)

**First: Prompting users using the new version you're currently developing**

1. You can search how to detect the app version using ios code, so that you can use this version to check your condition
2. If not available, you can define the app version somewhere globally in your project, (e.g. settings object, etc...)
3. Use this if and only if it's defined and have the required version

**Second: Prompting only users who already upgraded to a version X and higher**

1. Well, if you don't have to prompt them immediately, you can check the new versions for a specific action added to it, change the backend related to it to log users ids/emails and device id for example, and periodically send them the prompts

**Last: if you want to prompt users of old versions with the update**

1. You can use same technique as second part, but to log old users through a specific activity that was changed in the new version (this requires some sort of backward API compatibility)
2. Also you can search for any metadata info associated with the app API call in ios, it may include the version number, and start logging the users with future requests that have an old app version